# Can i get an aws lambda to run an rspec test?

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, webdrivers-gem

I got it working locally.
In aws i am getting an error.

Locally I use

### run_lambda_function.rb

```
require_relative 'lambda_function'
lambda_handler(event: {}, context: Object.new)
```

**Which calls**

### lambda_function.rb

```
require 'aws-sdk-lambda'
require 'json'
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'webdrivers'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  @@short_sleep = 1 # just for these viewing and debugging purposes :)
  Capybara.app_host = 'https://google.com'
  RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['spec/google_spec.rb']) #, $stderr, $stdout)
end
```

which uses spec:

### spec/google_spec.rb

```
describe 'Visi Websites', type: :feature do
  it 'can visit google' do
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_css('div')
    sleep @@short_sleep
  end
  it 'can visit gogole/forms' do
    visit '/forms'
    expect(page).to have_css('div')
    sleep @@short_sleep
  end
end
```

This runs locally but when I bundle to code to vendor/ and zip it all up, upload it to lambda (via S3 bucket due to size > 50k for dependencies*) and try to run it in aws mgtmt console I get an error in webdrivers:

[image]

I might be able to avoid with serverless and other approaches perhaps but I am trying to stay as simple and low-level without dependencies and aids while I am learning.  Within reason of course. No hoops.

- dependencies

## Gemfile

for locally bundling while testing, not relevant (I think) to uploaded code as I bundled that to /vendor and zipped it all (hence the large size and need for load via s3 bucket)

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
gem 'webdrivers'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

Comment: Is it some sort of GUI test?

Comment: yes it is a selenium browser test. wasn't sure it it work would. or would need to be headless or would not work

Comment: you are right, the best bet here would be to try the headless version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to run GUI based testing in Lambda environment. Lambda does not have access to display devices. You should try to run your test cases in the *headless* mode.